# How can I prevent the hash from being cleared when the URL is too long, as in OAuth token scenarios, using Webpack-Dev-Server via Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, webpack-dev-server

It appears that the webserver Angular CLI uses (Webpack-Dev-Server) for `ng serve` eliminates the hash fragment of the URL when the URL is too long. As an example, when getting a token back from an OAuth call:

```
http://localhost:4200/auth/sso#access_token=[access_token]&id_token=[ID_TOKEN]&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

With the access token and id token filled out, that URL can push to over 2000 characters. In my testing, it appears that somewhere around 1990 characters is the limit, and beyond that, the hash is cleared prior to the Angular app being requested. I looked through the Angular CLI code for instantiating the server and didn't see anything specific to the hash fragment there.

This is not a duplicate of questions about how to get the fragment from the URL in Angular, that works just fine when the URL hash fragment is shorter and the hash is passed through to the Angular app.

How can I prevent the hash from being cleared? Is this a Webpack Dev Server bug? This may not be specific to Angular if it that is the case.

This is not a duplicate of other stories related to Angular hashes, as it is specific to the Webpack-Dev-Server and how it handles long URLs with hash fragments.

Comment: ie11 has hash limit about 2000 symbols, is it your case? chrome can get it until 50k

Comment: Nope, this appears to be happening regardless of the browser, and actually seems to be happening in the Webpack local development server, not in the browser, or in the web app or Angular code.